# Airflow - Slack notification. I'm trying to configure slack notification when my program fails using airflow

Tags: python, notifications, airflow, slack

When I run the program, I receive a "broken dag no named module slackclient". I checked my code and setup my slack account.

I had included the necessary packages as well

```
from slackclient import SlackClient
from airflow.operators.slack_operator import SlackAPIPostOperator

failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
         task_id='shdfs',
         channel="#data",
         token="shdfgsdjh324353243brsrbewr3243",
         user= 'usr',
         text = "hi,this is notification"  )
```

Am I missing something? please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. You are missing slackclient module which the error message clearly tells. The problem might be solved by  `pip install slackclient`

Comment: Just reinstalled it, didn't work.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth, When I import slackclient on python interpreter, it imports successfully but when I run it on Airflow, Its giving me an error.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth I'm using pip.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth Hi, Just found out that when I import the package on python 2.7 its works, but doesn't work on python 3 when I import it. I think Airflow is trying to import the package from python3 but it generally runs on python2 Any idea how to change it ? Thanks.

Comment: Use virtualenv preferably always. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/

Comment: @NihalSangeeth Thanks buddy. Will look into it. Have a good one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following command and install slack dependencies and try again.

```
pip install apache-airflow[slack]
```

Answer (score 0):

Airflow was implemented with slackclient api version 'slackclient>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'.

from slackclient import SlackClient has been replaced with import slack in present slackclient version 2.5.0.
Change your slackclient version to slackclient>=1.0.0,<2.0.0 using this :

pip install 'slackclient>=1.0.0,<2.0.0'